# making the delete button appears only when hovering over the row. Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the delete button only appears on the row that the user hover over it. I did it using CSS but I am trying to find a way to do it using Bootstrap. here is a snippet of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="search_form">
        <div id="search_row" class="search-details">
            <div class="search_data">
                    <section id="form_input_section" class="d-flex flex-column">

                    </section>
                    <section id="form_add_button_row" class="d-flex flex-row flex-fill justify-content-around align-items-center form-group">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Input...">
                        <button type="button" id="btn_remove_row" >Delete</button>
                    </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. First of all, you hover over a div, not over a row, despite you IDíng it with a `row`. A row is a `tr` in a table in html terms. Second, where is your CSS and/or your javascript (the later you dont need technically, but maybe add an action to it). Without it, we cant help. Also, we dont write it for you, we just like to give pointers or push you in the right direction with more correct code. Anyway, gotta look into the `CSS` for this, with a main target and a sub target, so say `#btn_remove_row{display: none}` and later on call `#search_row:hover #btn_remove_row{display: block}`

Comment: thanks for the feedback. This will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your answer, as I put down in the comments earlier. You require a start state, which in your case will be the `display: none` on your id `#btn_remove_row` and as you hover over the `#search_row` you target the `#btn_remove_row` specific id again to chance it's perspective.

Working example here: https://www.codeply.com/p/HmGBqPCgnF

Or as your code supplies

```
#btn_remove_row{display: none} 
#search_row:hover #btn_remove_row{display: block}
```

I suggest making it a table and use classes, rather than ID's. This will give you more control and helps you align everything correctly.

Comment: Thank you ! I will change it to table and use classes. I was not sure if that was a good way to do it. thanks again.

Comment: If this awnser solves your problem, would you like to mark the awnser as accepted (and preferly rate it) so other people know its solved.